# Shared NSManagedObjectContext with multiple performBlock calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm working on a program which repeatedly needs to fetch new data, parse it and store it using Core Data. One of the problems is that the data is split up over multiple web service requests and so the parsing needs to be split up in various parts before the final object is assembled. All the parsing also needs to happen in the background.

I thought about creating a new `NSManagedObjectContext` per request, but then the problem is that I have to find a way to pass my objects from one context to the other and that seems quite tricky to me, considering it can easily take 10 parsing steps until the object is complete.

So now I thought about using a single `NSManagedObjectContext` initialised with a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. It seems to work fine, except that sometimes I will receive an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in one step of the flow. So my question is, am I on the right path here? I know that I can nest multiple `performBlock` calls and that core data will take care of the threading. But can I also use multiple non-nested performBlock calls spread over time (which is what I'm doing), as long as they are all running on the same `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: Should you be using 1 entity in the model, or many? Why does it take so many requests to get the data back? Show your code and an exception message and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented it like this and it turns out it works fine.